# Post data to Controller from RestController spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am integrating  web application with another web application. In this integration i needs to capture data using api to do so i used @RestController class , to post data to the third party application i have to use form submission is there any possible way to do this? how can i do a form submission through a rest controller without showing a form

Comment: Rest controller all used to be called, to call third party application, you use things like HttpClient in your application, that's what you should look deep into, I think.

Comment: If i understand correctly your question, i think you need to search an http client like WebClient or RestTemplate.